# Magnetic moment of an silver atom

Tags: magnetic-moment

[image]

Image from Sakurai, Modern quantum mechanics.

**Question**: Why $\partial_z(\mu\cdot B)\simeq\mu_z \partial_z B_z$? it's because $\mu_z$ is constant with respect to the $z$-axis? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Everywhere along the path of the flying silver atoms the magnetic field
$\mathbf{B}$ is pointing in $z$ direction,
i.e. the components $B_x$ and $B_y$ are zero.

[image: Stern-Gerlach-Experiment]
<sub>(image from [Lexikon der Physik - Stern-Gerlach-Experiment](https://www.spektrum.de/lexikon/physik/stern-gerlach-experiment/13847))</sub>

Therefore the dot product simplifies to
$$\mathbf{\mu}\cdot\mathbf{B}=\mu_xB_x+\mu_yB_y+\mu_zB_z =\mu_zB_z.$$

The [magnetic moment $\mathbf{\mu}$ is a property of the atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Magnetic_moment_of_an_atom).
Its magnitude $|\mu|$ is constant and characteristic for the atom.
Its direction can change because an external magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$
[exerts a torque $\mathbf{\tau}=\mathbf{\mu}\times\mathbf{B}$ on the magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Torque_on_a_moment).
So when the magnetic moment $\mathbf{\mu}$ is aligned with the
field $\mathbf{B}$ (like here in the Stern-Gerlach experiment),
then there is no torque, and hence $\mathbf{\mu}$ stays constant.

Hence we finally have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\mu\cdot\mathbf{B})
=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(\mu_zB_z)
=\mu_z\frac{\partial B_z}{\partial z}$$

Comment: But, why $\mu_z$ is constant? is a law physics? thanks

Comment: @eraldcoil I have added some elaboration on this.

Comment: thanks. then, we can say that, because $|\mu|$ is constant, then $\mu_z$ is constant? or $\tau=0$ implies that $\mu_z=0$?

Comment: @eraldcoil $\mathbf{\mu}\parallel\vec{B} \implies \mathbf{\tau}=\mathbf{0}
\implies \mathbf{\mu}=$ const $\implies \mu_z=$ const

Answer (score 0):

In the expression $\partial_z(\mu \cdot B)$, $\mu$ is a constant, so it's the same as $\mu \cdot \partial_z B$. And since it says we ignore all other components of $B$, the only term that contributes is the one containing $B_z$, namely $\mu_z \partial_z B_z$.

Moreover, even in situations where $\mu$ is a function of position (e.g. when computing the force density exerted upon a magnetized material) the formula $F = \nabla(\mu \cdot B)$ is still supposed to be interpreted to mean that $\mu$ is treated as a constant by the $\nabla$. To be more precise, it should say something like $F(x) = \left[\nabla'(\mu(x) \cdot  B(x'))\right]_{x'=x}$.

Comment: $\mu$ or $|\mu|$ constant?

Comment: @eraldcoil $\mu$ is constant for the purposes of the spatial derivative in this particular formula. It may be temporally varying but that's irrelevant.